# Bean Spec and apache-commons-beanutils (capitalization of getter)

Tags: apache-commons-beanutils

We have a Bean with a field called:

```
private String aBcde = ... ;
```

the getter was written:

```
public String getABcde() {
    return aBcde;
}
```

but

http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.8.0/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.java.html

reports a "NoSuchMethodError"

**Question: Is the name of the getter wrong, or is this a bug in BeanUtils?**

Pls Note that this works fine:

```
public String getaBcde() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://blog.950buy.com/article/javabean-specification-on-a-few-you-should-know/ it seems my expectiation was wrong and

```
public String getaBcde() {
  ...
}
```

is correct.

Actually, the Bean Spec says:

"However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone. So for example:

- “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
- “Z” becomes “z”
- “URL” becomes “URL”"

So in my case I had getter "getABcde" which maps to property "ABcde", cf. the URL example.